# cannot connect to PostgreSQL server locally

Tags: postgresql, osx-yosemite

My computer crashed while running a PostgreSQL server(9.4) on OSX(10.10.3) and I'm now getting an issue when I either try to log on from terminal/command line or pgAdminIII.  I took the advice found here, and wasn't able to find /usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid but was able to find /Library/PostgresQL/9.4/data/postmaster.pid.  I deleted the latter file and upon resetting, I got a new error message stating that "postgres" role does not exist.  In a panic, I immediately restored postmaster.pid and am back to square one with "could not connect to server.  Is the server running locally and accepting connections on unix domain socket '/tmp/.s.pgsql.5432'?"  Any help in resolving this would be much appreciated.  I installed PostgreSQL using the universal binary installer from the PSQL website.

I had fixed this by uninstalling and reinstalling PostgreSQL, but was hoping for a more elegant and clean approach like the one I thought I found in removing postmaster.pid, especially if I'm going to be working with extensive databases in the future.  Thank you.

Comment: This Question might do better on the database admin StackExchange: http://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Is "9.6" a mistake? Postgres 9.4 is current, 9.5 in development, no 9.6 that I've heard of.

Comment: yes. Thank you for catching that.  I've corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

For Mac OS X, I would recommend using [Postgres.app](http://posgresapp.com/)

Comment: I wasn't able to find any information on whether drivers can be installed on top of Postgres.app like they can with the dbenterprise version using stack builder.  Is that possible, since I'd be using the pgjdbc driver for a webapp app that I'm working on?

Comment: I just tried to go through Postgres.app to no avail due to the issue described here where libpq is not being picked up: https://github.com/PostgresApp/PostgresApp/issues/42